# play TextToSpeech when the activity starting

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want my application speak a sentence "Hello, If Your Case Is Emergency CALL 911" when the activity starting, but i cannot do that.

i had used the following code:

```
public class home extends AppCompatActivity  implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    Button Signin , listButton,Speak;
    EditText Text;
    Button mSpeak;
    private TextToSpeech mTTS;
    protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

      //  TTS 
        mTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        mSpeak =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.mSpeak);
        mSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                speak("Hello, If Your Case Is Emergency CALL 911 , IF not Continue");
            }
        });

        speak("Hello, If Your Case Is Emergency CALL 911 , IF not Continue");
    }


    public void speak(String str) {
          mTTS.speak(str, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mTTS.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            int result = mTTS.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            mTTS.setPitch(0.8f);
            mTTS.setSpeechRate(1.1f);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "Language not supported");
            } else {
                mSpeak.setEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initialization failed");
        }
    }
}
```

in the previous code the `speak(str)` method used to run TTS and let devise start speaking.
however, when i try to run `TextToSpeech` when the `mSpeak` Button pressed, it work correctly. **but**, when run it on `onCreate` it not work.

I want that when the activity starts the `TextToSpeech` should play. Anybody could please guide me the right way to do it as it is not working. The `TextToSpeech` ONLY works with the button press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats because TTS is initializing for a while, pretty fast, but still you can't create `new TextToSpeech` and almost immediatelly few lines below call `mTTS.speak`. at this moment you don't know is TTS available - you must wait for `status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS` (and also language available confirmation), so you should move you "welcome" speak method call there

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        int result = mTTS.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
        mTTS.setPitch(0.8f);
        mTTS.setSpeechRate(1.1f);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "Language not supported");
        } else {
            mSpeak.setEnabled(true);
            speak("Hello, If Your Case Is Emergency CALL 911 , IF not Continue");
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initialization failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: will Done , Thank You :)